# How to have an unordered list float to right?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm having issues with a little feature on my site's products' page 'tools' bar. I want to have it float to the right of my site's breadcrumb navigation, making it inline with the breadcrumb navigation. But it's going to the next line.

**Here's what it looks like:**

```
<div id="breadcrumbsForStore">
<h5>

<a href="/" title="store home">Home</a>
{% for category in product.categories limit:1 %} / {{ category | link_to }}{% endfor %} /
<a href="{{ page.full_url }}" title="{{ page.name }}">{{ page.name }}</a>
</h5>
<ul id="shoptools"><li>SIZE GUIDE / Filter:</li></ul>
</div>
```

**And here's the CSS:**

```
#breadcrumbsForStore{width:960px; font-family: futura; text-align:left;margin:20px 0px 25px 0;padding:0px 0 5px 0;clear:both; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-transform:uppercase;}
#breadcrumbsForStore h5{font-size:10px; font-family: futura;}
#breadcrumbsForStore h5 a{color:#525252; border-bottom:0px dotted #0d0d0d; letter-spacing:1px; padding: 10px 3px 10px 3px;}
#breadcrumbsForStore h5 a:hover{color: #0d0d0d;}
ul#shoptools{float:right; display:inline;}
ul#shoptools li{float:left; display:inline;}
```

**Here's where the problem is (it says "SIZE GUIDE / FILTER:")**
http://shopmoonfall.bigcartel.com/products

Comment: Put the `ul#shoptools` as the first child of `#breadcrumbsForStore` element, before the links. And don't forget to clear the *float* at the end of the `#breadcrumbsForStore`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your html like this:

```
<div id="breadcrumbsForStore">
<ul id="shoptools"><li>SIZE GUIDE / Filter:</li></ul>
<h5>
<a href="/" title="store home">Home</a>
{% for category in product.categories limit:1 %} / {{ category | link_to }}{% endfor %} /
<a href="{{ page.full_url }}" title="{{ page.name }}">{{ page.name }}</a>
</h5>
</div>
```

Comment: For some reason, it floated to the right, but it's still just a little lower than the breadcrumb, still. Anyway to fix it besides a negative margin-top?

Comment: as per @Mike comment below, h5 {display: inline-block}

Answer (score 1):

The H5 element is display:block style by default.  If you add a style to make it inline, like

```
 h5 {display: inline-block}
```

then floating elements will show next to it.

Fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/t84yU/

(note I changed your width from 960 px to 560 px also, just to make it more readable)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear on what your trying to do but the way you nested the `<h5>` is kinda ugly.

If you want the `<ul>` on the same line as the `<a>` tags you should include the `<ul>` in the `<h5>` tag.

If you don't want to include the `<ul>` in the `<h5>`, make sure the `<h5>` is `display: inline;` also. All elements on the "line" must be `display: inline/inline-block;` for it to appear on one line. Headers are `display: block;` by default so the `<h5>` is pushing down the unordered list.